# How to get the first row values in sql server query

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

My requirement is AllowedAmount for any latest **postdate** with latest **PaymentID**.I have tried many times just to get the firstrow value .But i get 2 rows instead.I tried using **rownumber()** but its not applicable after selecting  for all patient name it doesn't give correct output .Does any one has another method apart from **top 1** and **rownumber() partition**.
**My requirement is get One ChargeID with AllowedAmount for the latest Postdate with latest PaymentID**

```
SELECT
DISTINCT
  TM.[PatientName] AS [PATIENT NAME],
  [dbo].[SplitString](TM.InsPlanName, '(') AS [ Insurance],
  ISNULL(TMmm1.ChargeAmount, 0) AS [Amount Billed],
  ISNULL(TMM1.AllowedAmount, 0) AS AllowedAmount,
  TMM1.PostDate,
  TMM1.PaymentID,
  TM.ChargeID AS ChargeID

FROM [MasterReport] AS TM
LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT
  SUM(ISNULL(ChargeAmount, 0)) AS ChargeAmount,
  [ChargeID]
FROM [dbo].[TransactionMasterReport]
WHERE transactiontype = 'Charges'
GROUP BY [ChargeID]) AS TMmm1
  ON TM.ChargeID = TMmm1.ChargeID


LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT
  MAX(PostDate) AS PostDate,
  MAX(ISNULL(PaymentID, 0)) AS PaymentID,
  [ChargeID],
  AllowedAmount
FROM [dbo].[TransactionMasterReport]
WHERE ([TransactionType] = 'Payments'
OR [TransactionType] = 'Adjustments')
AND AllowedAmount >= 1
AND PaymentSource LIKE '%Primary%'
GROUP BY [ChargeID],
         PostDate,
         AllowedAmount,
         PaymentID) AS TMM1
  ON TM.[ChargeID] = TMM1.[ChargeID]

WHERE TM.ChargeId = 4255

ORDER BY TM.[ChargeID]
```

[image: ouput]

When I use top 1 in left outer join I get 0.00 in allowed Amount which is incorrect .

Comment: Did you try order by `POSTDATE`, `PaymentID` then get the first row?

Comment: I tried still its showing the same output

Comment: Sample data would have been very helpful here.  For future reference, please see [mcve] for details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work, after you play with it for syntax errors.  I do not have tables nor data that match yours.  The changes are in the second LeftJoin to use Row_Number ordered by Descending of your fields.  You may need to enclose the whole thing in another Select (...) and move the Where RN1 = 1 below that.

```
SELECT
DISTINCT
  TM.[PatientName] AS [PATIENT NAME],
  [dbo].[SplitString](TM.InsPlanName, '(') AS [ Insurance],
  ISNULL(TMmm1.ChargeAmount, 0) AS [Amount Billed],
  ISNULL(TMM1.AllowedAmount, 0) AS AllowedAmount,
  TMM1.PostDate,
  TMM1.PaymentID,
  TM.ChargeID AS ChargeID

FROM [MasterReport] AS TM
LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT
  SUM(ISNULL(ChargeAmount, 0)) AS ChargeAmount,
  [ChargeID]
FROM [dbo].[TransactionMasterReport]
WHERE transactiontype = 'Charges'
GROUP BY [ChargeID]) AS TMmm1
  ON TM.ChargeID = TMmm1.ChargeID



LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT 
             PostDate,
             ISNULL(PaymentID, 0) AS PaymentID,
             ChargeID,
             AllowedAmount,
             Row_Number() Over(Partition By ChargeID  Order By PostDate Desc, PaymentID Desc) as RN1
FROM [dbo].[TransactionMasterReport]
WHERE ([TransactionType] = 'Payments'
    OR [TransactionType] = 'Adjustments')
AND AllowedAmount >= 1
AND PaymentSource LIKE '%Primary%'
) AS TMM1

  ON TM.[ChargeID] = TMM1.[ChargeID]

WHERE  RN1 = 1
  and  TM.ChargeId = 4255

ORDER BY TM.[ChargeID]
```

Answer (score 0):

We don't know the actual scenario but as `suggested above` it should work but as you said it's again returning the same output so use query as a `subquery` as below and try

To return only one record from the whole output

```
SELECT TOP 1 *
FROM ( <your query> )
ORDER BY postdate, paymentid DESC
```

To return `top 1` value of each `ChargeID`

```
SELECT TOP (1) WITH TIES *
FROM ( <your query> )
GROUP BY ChargeID
ORDER BY postdate, paymentid DESC
```

Comment: It  seems that  "WHERE TM.ChargeId = 4255"  is only for one example charge, and in reality there are many IDs that will probably be on the final report.  There is a trailing  "ORDER BY TM.[ChargeID]"

Comment: Updated, please use the second solution to retrieve `top 1` value of each `ChargeID` and remove `WHERE TM.ChargeId = 4255` to run for all the `ChargeID`s

Answer (score 0):

I think, you should change your query like,

```
SELECT TOP 1 <your fields>
FROM [MasterReport] AS TM
LEFT OUTER JOIN  <TMmm1> ON TM.ChargeID = TMmm1.ChargeID
LEFT OUTER JOIN  <TMM1> ON TM.[ChargeID] = TMM1.[ChargeID]
WHERE TM.ChargeId = 4255
ORDER BY TMM1.PostDate DESC, TMM1.PaymentID DESC
```

It will give you only one row(`TOP 1`) and it will be the latest `PostDate` & `PaymentID`